# json serialization: cannot handle a sequence of length 3 start location

Tags: json, xml, xquery

I am trying to convert a xml which is full of information about books ans echa author, price and some more data (biblio.xml) to  json, but the error

```
json serialization: cannot handle a sequence of length 3 start location
```

keeps showing and i dont know what is happening, I have search hoow to transformit and this way should work, I dont even understand what the error means.

The result i want is this:

```
    [{  "author": [ "W. Stevens"  ],  "title":"TCP\/IP Illustrated", "year":"1994"},
     {  "author": [ "W. Stevens" ],  "title":"Advanced Programming ...", "year":"1992" },
     {  "author": [ "Serge Abiteboul", "Peter Buneman",  "Dan Suciu"  ],  "title":"Data on the Web", "year":"2000"  },
     ]
```

My biblio.xml is this:

```
 <bib>
        <book year="1994">
            <title>TCP/IP Illustrated</title>
            <author>
                <last>Stevens</last>
                <first>W.</first>
            </author>
            <publisher>Addison-Wesley</publisher>
            <price>65.95</price>
        </book>
    </bib>    
        <book year="1992">
        <title>Advanced Programming in the Unix environment</title>
        <author>
            <last>Stevens</last>
            <first>W.</first>
        </author>
        <publisher>Addison-Wesley</publisher>
        <price>65.95</price>
    </book>
    <book year="2000">
        <title>Data on the Web</title>
        <author>
            <last>Abiteboul</last>
            <first>Serge</first>
        </author>
        <author>
            <last>Buneman</last>
            <first>Peter</first>
        </author>
        <author>
            <last>Suciu</last>
            <first>Dan</first>
        </author>
        <publisher>Morgan Kaufmann Publishers</publisher>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
```

My xquery is :

```
xquery version "3.1";
declare namespace array = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array";
declare namespace map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:method "json";


for $books in (doc('../biblio.xml')/bib/book) 
return 
   array {
   map{"author": [$books/author/text()]},
   map{"title": $books/title/text()},
   map{"year" : $books/@year}
  }
```

I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want an array populated with three maps (well, one map for each `book` element):

```
array {
for $books in (doc('test2018032201.xml')/bib/book) 
return 
   map{"author":  array { $books/author/(first || ' ' || last)},
       "title": $books/title/data(),
       "year" : $books/@year/data()
  }
}
```

while your approach returns three arrays (one for each book).

Online sample at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Y4

If we replace the `for .. in` with the `!` operator the expression is more compact:

```
array {
/bib/book ! map{
       "author":  array { author/(first || ' ' || last)},
       "title": title/data(),
       "year" : @year/data()
  }
}
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Y4/1